# Error occured while installing Oracle Developer 6i on Windows 10 (64-Bit)

Tags: windows-10, permissions, 64-bit, oracle-10g

I have recently installed Windows 10 (64-Bit) Operating system on my computer and tried installing Oracle Developer 6i (Forms & Reports) but to no avail. It keeps failing and showing an error which says the **msvcrt40.dll** file could not be copied due to permission issue.

Then I manually downloaded the `msvcrt40.dll` file from the internet and enforced permissions on the `system32` folder hoping this trick would work but no luck there either. Screenshot of the error message is attached below.

Need a quick fix. Would appreciate the help.

[image: msvcrt40.dll Permission Error]

Comment: Have you tried installing as an Administrator?

Comment: i have fixed the msvcrt40 issue but now have another problem.please see if you have a fix for this : ODBC Error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398173/error-creating-connection-to-oracle-odbc-in-excel

Comment: How about answer this question first?  When somebody has an answer to your other question it will get answered. No sense in pushing for an answer before that happens though

Comment: Check the solution of your question in this forum: [https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/oracle-forms-and-reports-6i-installation-on/7c639862-47e4-4667-8578-ffbc0e2ca9fc](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/oracle-forms-and-reports-6i-installation-on/7c639862-47e4-4667-8578-ffbc0e2ca9fc) Apparently he has the same problem as you, which they gave an answer to! I hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on [the website of Bayu Pinasthika (developer of Ondonesia)](https://bayu.pinasthika.com/ti/oracle/install-oracle-forms-reports-6i-di-windows-10/)

---

> I'm trying to install Oracle Forms / Reports 6i on Windows 10 64-bit. During installation there is a warning as below.
>
> "A PERMISSION DENIED ERROR while trying to copy `E:\oracle 6i\` path to `c:\windows\system32\MSVCRT40.DLL`". Would you like to retry the operation, ignore the error, or allow the error to be processed by the installer".
>
> This makes me wonder why when installing in Windows 8 smoothly, but in Windows 10 there is a problem. However after meeting om google, I gave instructions that is by deleting some lines in the installation file.
>
> Open file \ win32 \ ssf \ 6_0_0_0_0 \ install \ SSF60.INS with a text editor (example: Notepad ++). Remove lines 219 to 231 in the following sections:
>
> ```
> copy(dll_rest);
> /******************
> Install ODBC support
> *******************/
> ui_action(instantiate(install_files));
> copy(odbc1);
> copy(odbc3);
> {copy(odbc2,"%operating_system%");}
> ['WRITE_ERROR: continue();] /*the current NT installer is using ctl3d32.dll which is in this
> odbc2 group. This is causing write errors in .ins*/
> copy(shrdll,"%operating_system%");
> ```
>
> Once deleted, install oracle forms / reports as usual.

Had to translate this (big thanks to Google Translate) from Bahia Indonesia to English.

Works on Windows 10 x64 Enterprise.